# Publish ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, deployment, razor-pages, publish

Can't find a way to just publish a single cshtml page (no code-behind cshtml.cs involved). It feels like I'm missing something. This should be a super common thing to do.

So, when I choose to publish single file option from VS, it deploys both cshtml and cshtml.cs files. But for Razor Pages, it all compiles to dll. There aren't actual pages after publish.

So, it's possible to archive this instead of publishing the whole project for small html changes? Thank you.

[Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2nPV.png)

Comment: You can't do that because the .cshtml and .cs files are both used to render the HTML.  The ".cs" file is the sort of controller/model, while the .cshtml file is a sort of template.  render() uses both to output the HTML to the browser.  You CAN have a .cs file without a .cshtml file, though.  (ex: JS call to a controller where the controller doesn't return a PageObject.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So regarding the deployment, if we only make changes on a cshtml file without modifying the corresponding code-behind CS file. But still, we have to republish the whole project? That doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** No, it is not possible to publish only `.cshtml` files in Razor Page.

---

*Difference*

A single **razor page** consists of `.cshtml` and `.cshtml.cs` files.

A single **Razor view page** only has one `.cshtml` file.

---

**Workaround**
If you really need to modify the page separately, I recommend adding MVC to your Razor Page project, so that you can publish the .cshtml file separately.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! Oops changing the whole structure of the project to MVC. That's a big one. Let's not consider that for now, lol. So, is it not possible to update HTML content on Razor pages (.cshtml files) without the need to publish the entire project, even for minor front-end changes?